# Java buffered greyscale image byte and int

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, grayscale

Please, please can someone explain below to me. Its driving me nuts. I am playing with creating 8-bit grayscale images from arrays in java.

The code below should produce black > white horiz gradients. Parts 1 and 2 do produce desired image, but in the int[] passed to `getimageFromarray` in **1** goes from -128 to 127, and in **2** goes from 0 to 255, yet they produce the same image. **3** produces the (undesired) image I would expected **1** to produce, going on its max and min values alone.

Why is this? How can this be?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test {

    final static int WIDTH = 320;
    final static int HEIGHT = 256;

    // Black and white as int
    final static int BLACK = 0;
    final static int WHITE = 255;
    //...same, but not
    final static int BLACK_WRONG = 127;
    final static int WHITE_WRONG = -128;

    // Black and white as byte val
    final static byte BLACK_BYTE = -0x80; //i.e -128
    final static byte WHITE_BYTE = 0x7f; // i.e. 127



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        int[] pixels = new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
        int[] m;

        // Generates gradient1.bmp
        // produces as expected - black at top, white at bottom
        int numb=0,c=0;
        byte grey1 = BLACK;
        while (numb<pixels.length){

            // inc through greyscales down image
            if (c>WIDTH){
                grey1++;
                c=0;
            }       

            // cast from byte to int
            pixels[numb] = grey1; 

            // inc column and count
            c++;
            numb++;
        }

        m = getMaxMin(pixels); // max 127 , min -128
        System.out.printf("Maxmin %s; %s;\n",m[0], m[1]);
        getImageFromArray("gradient1.bmp", pixels,WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //*************************************************************************
        // Generates gradient3.bmp
        // produces as expected - black at top, white at bottom

        numb=0;     
        c=0;
        int grey2 = BLACK; //i.e zero
        while (numb<pixels.length){

            // inc through greyscales down image
            if (c>WIDTH){
                grey2++;
                c=0;
            }       

            // no cast
            pixels[numb] = grey2; 

            // inc column and count
            c++;
            numb++;
        }

        m = getMaxMin(pixels); // max 255, min 0
        System.out.printf("Maxmin %s; %s;\n",m[0], m[1]);
        getImageFromArray("gradient2.bmp", pixels,WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //*************************************************************************
        // Generates gradient3.bmp
        // produces as unexpected - midgrey > white. black > midgrey
        numb=0;     
        c=0;
        byte grey3 = BLACK_BYTE; //i.e zero
        while (numb<pixels.length){

            // inc through greyscales down image
            if (c>WIDTH){
                grey3++;
                c=0;
            }       

            // no cast
            pixels[numb] = grey3; 

            // inc column and count
            c++;
            numb++;
        }

        m = getMaxMin(pixels); // max 127 , min -128
        System.out.printf("Maxmin %s; %s;\n",m[0], m[1]);
        getImageFromArray("gradient3.bmp", pixels,WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }



//*******************************************************************************
    static int sWidth,sHeight = 0;        
    static BufferedImage sImage = null;
    static WritableRaster sRaster=null;

    public static BufferedImage getImageFromArray(String filename, int pixels[], int width, int height) throws IOException {
        if (sImage == null){
        sImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        sRaster = sImage.getRaster();
        }

        sRaster.setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(sImage, "bmp", new FileOutputStream(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sImage;
    }


    static int[] getMaxMin(int[] v){
        int max=0,min=0;
        for (int i:v){
            if (i>max) max = i;
            if (i<min) min = i;
        }
        int[] r = {max,min};
        return r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `BufferedImage` takes RGBA (or similarly) encoded colors as input, you needs to properly construct those `int`s from their respective RGBA components.

To convert the signed bytes `R = 0`, `G = 0`, `B = 0`, `A = 127` for *GRAY*, you'd have convert them to unsigned `int`s and combine them into one `int`, like so:

```
int color = (((A & 0xff) << 24 | ((B & 0xff) << 16) | ((G << 8) | (R & 0xff));
```

This is the same as assigning the hex values of *7f 7f 7f ff*. 
The `& 0xff` masking is necessary to properly convert the signed bytes (-128 to 127) to an unsigned int (0 to 255).

The `<<` 'left shifts' the bytes around inside the int.

You may have to change the input order of RGBA to get the correct result.

Comment: thx for (sole!) answer. Yeah, the `BufferedImage` is set to `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` so only takes one value per pixel, but useful when I move onto RGBA stuff nevertheless. With a quick google, I think there is something in unsigned vs. signed int/bytes you mention. Will look into that and see if its the source of my confusion.